# Using SqlCommand with C# Variables

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

This is probably a somewhat remedial question, but I'm currently looking to update our database with content from an XML file created in and run through Visual Studio, and I'm fairly certain of what my mistake is, but not how to correct it. Working with Fields field0-field12, this is what I have for each of them.

```
string strField0; //strField0 - strField12
var doc = XDocument.Load("serializer.xml");

foreach (var xe in doc.Root.Elements("UserReportPreviewListDto"))
{
    XElement field0 = xe.Element("Field0");
    ConvertField(xe, "Field0", TranslateValueField);
    if (field0 != null)
    {
        strField0 = field0.Value;
    }
}
//strField0 - strField12
```

Below, I call the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` thusly.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string update =
    "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] ([Code], [Description], [SendEmail], [Type], [CustomForeColor], Inactive], [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate], [ModifiedById], [CreatedById], [StartDate], [EndDate])
    VALUES (strField1, strField2, strField3, strField4, strField5, strField6, strField7, strField8, strField9, strField10, strField11, strField12)";
SqlCommand upd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
conn.Open();
upd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm sure my mistake is in trying to use variables declared in Visual Studio in the Values field of that SQL statement, but I'm not quite sure of what the best workaround for that would be. Additionally, when it comes time to call `SqlCommand upd`, I'm not sure I'm doing that properly with `upd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

I hope I'm clear on what I'm asking for with this. If not, please let me know. Any kind of assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error it returns when run is
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'strField1'.

Invalid column name 'strField2'.`

Comment: [Parameters, man. Use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#exampleToggle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a parameterized query like this

```
string update = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] ([Code], [Description], [SendEmail], 
                  [Type], [CustomForeColor], [Inactive], [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate], 
                  [ModifiedById], [CreatedById], [StartDate], [EndDate])
                  VALUES (@code, @description, @sendemail, @type, @forecol, @inactive,
                          @moddate, @createdate,@modby, @createby,@start, @end)";

string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
    { 
        ParameterName = "@code", 
        SqlDbType=SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
        Size=25,  // or whatever size you have for this field in the table 
        Value = strField1
    });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
    { 
        ParameterName = "@description", 
        SqlDbType=SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
        Size=255, // Same as before, the size should be equal to the field length on the table
        Value = strField2
    });
    .... and so on for the other parameters ....
    upd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I stopped to add parameters to the collection just after two examples, but you need to add the other parameters for every parameter placeholder present in the query. (The **@xxxx**) and most important; you need to specify the exact data type expected by the underlying table.

For example, the `StartDate` field is probably a datetime field and thus its parameter should be defined to be of `SqlDbType.DateTime`, something like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{ 
     ParameterName = "@start", 
     SqlDbType=SqlDbType.DateTime, 
     Value = Convert.ToDateTime(strField11)
});
```

Notice that for parameters of type NVarChar is important to define the max size of the string passed. This allows the query optimizer of sqlserver to store the execution plan and reuse it if you call it again with the same parameter sizes. This is an [interesting article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) about it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Steve. It's looking good so far, but for each entry, it's giving me an error for "Use of unassigned local variable 'strFieldX'", though their values are assigned in the XElement statements above. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you look at it, the error message is correct. The variables strFieldX are assigned only if the `if (field0 != null)` condition is true. So, if the field condition is false the variable is never initialized. The compiler cannot know what will be the result at runtime of that condition and emits the error message. You could fix this problem assigning a default value to the strFieldX variables when you declare them. IE: `string strField0 = string.Empty;`

Comment: I'm running into issues where date fields have null values and are unable to be converted and written into the Insert statement. Any thoughts on a fix for that?

Comment: I suggest to post a new question. In this way more people could look at your problem than the few that are still looking at this question and you could get faster answers. If this answer or another one here resolves your original question then choose the best fit for your problem. Otherwise this could become the disliked pattern of [Chamaleon Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You have to conver it to paramters liek that

```
string update = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] ([Code], [Description], [SendEmail]....)
    VALUES (@strField1, @strField2, @strField3, ..";
SqlCommand upd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
upd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strField1", "1"); 
   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the C# variables in a string literal, they won't be detected and interpreted as a column because you have not wrapped them in apostrophes like: `'strField1'`. However, you should use sql-parameters anyway, most important because it prevents sql-injection.

```
string update = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] (
                    [Code], [Description], [SendEmail], 
                    [Type], [CustomForeColor], [Inactive], [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate], 
                    [ModifiedById], [CreatedById], [StartDate], [EndDate])
                  VALUES (@Code, @Description, @SendEmail,@Type, @CustomForeColor, @Inactive,
                    @ModifiedDate, @CreatedDate, @ModifiedById, @CreatedById, @StartDate, @EndDate)";
SqlCommand upd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
upd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strField1;
upd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strField2;
upd.Parameters.Add("@SendEmail", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = boolField;
// and so on ....
conn.Open();
upd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Use the correct types, so for example instead of passing always strings pass a `DateTime` for a `datetime` column and a `bool` to a `bit` column(that's why i've used `boolField`). If you need to convert them you can use the appropriate methods, for example `int.Parse` or `DateTime.Parse`.